# Show that, without determining them, that $\ker (h)$ and $\text{im} (h)$ are orthogonal in $\mathbb {R}^3$ and $E=\ker (h)\oplus \text{im} (h)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

The space $ \mathbb {R}^3 $ is endowed with its usual scalar product, noted $ \langle. ,. \rangle $ for which the canonical basis $ \mathcal {B} = (e_1, e_2, e_3) $ is orthonormal.

We denote by $ h $ the endomorphism of $ \mathbb {R}^3 $ whose canonical matrix is

$$H=\left(\begin{matrix}1& -2& 3\\-2 &3 &-4\\3& -4 &5\end{matrix}\right)$$

**Problem**

Show that, without determining them, that $\ker (h)$ and $\operatorname{im} (h)$ are orthogonal in $\mathbb {R}^3$ and $E=\ker (h)\oplus \operatorname{im} (h)$.

An idea please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $H$ is symmetric that is $H^T=H$. Now if $x\in\text{ker}(h)$ and $h(y)\in\text{im}(h)$ we have
$$h(y)\cdot x=(Hy)^Tx=y^TH^Tx=y^THx=y\cdot h(x)=0$$
since $h(x)=0$. We make use of the formula
$$a\cdot b=a^Tb$$
The direct sum should be obvious since if $F$ is any subspace we have
$$E=F\oplus F^{\perp}$$